# What's the simplest way to wrap extruded text around a cylinder?

Tags: modeling, text-object

What's the simplest way to wrap extruded text around a cylinder that has a specific radius (for example, the label on a can of baked beans)?

I've tried using the `Simple Deform` modifier, but that (a) doesn't allow you to choose a radius and (b) requires the text to be converted to a curve.

I'm trying to model a cylinder with radius of 30, which has a line of embossed text that runs around the curved side, facing outward.

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try using a [*Curve modifier*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Deform/Curve).

1. Add curve circle (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Curve Circle*) and set the radius as desired in the *Redo menu* (at the bottom of the *Tool Shelf*):

   [image]
2. Add the text object (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Text*) and type in your text (<kbd>Tab</kbd>*> Edit mode*):

   [image]
3. Add a *[curve modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Deform/Curve)* to the text object in *Properties > Modifiers*, and set the *Object* to be your curve circle:

   [image]
4. Rotate the text object `90` degrees on the X axis (<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>90</kbd>) and then scale by `-1` again on the X (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd>):

   [image]
5. Increase the *Extrude* value in *Properties > Text > Geometry* to give the text some thickness:

   [image]

   Optionally increase the *Depth* and *Resolution* values for *Bevel* to round the edges a bit.

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Notice there is some odd distortion with deformed text (top of the 'T'), you may want to apply Subdivision-Surface and set it to 'Simple' to reduce distortion artifacts before distortion happens.

Comment: @ideasman42 "T" distortion is due to low amount of vertices. When Text object use modifier is automaticly meshed (triangulated). Letter "T" has only corner vertices in shape. To get it correct - text has to be converted to curve. For more info see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/160721/2214

Answer (score 4):

You could simply add BezierCircle to the scene and add a *Curve Modifier* to text object

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found you must also use the keystroke Alt + C on the text in order to apply the modifier. If you don't do this then you can't apply the modifier, and if you don't apply it then the text will not be wrapped when you render.

So get the text exactly the way you want it as described by gandalf3, above, and then hit Alt + C, then apply the modifier. This took me about an hour to find out why I couldn't get it to work after I'd gone through the steps, so I figured I'd come back here and post this extra info. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but except for a special case, there is no need to convert the text. Your answer may be interesting if you provide some more information (pictures), to illustrate the need of converting the text. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I have had to export to curves, also, and use NutsCircle instead of bezierCircle.
Using bezierCircle, the circle radius is arbitrary (it adapts itself to text instead of adapting text to circle radius).
Also, if text is not exported to curves, there is no "extrude" control.

Comment: Do you mean Nurbs Circle? You can extrude any text much like you can extrude any curve object. Also you don't "export" to curves, you convert.

Comment: You do have *Extrude* option in the Geometry rollout in the text object properties which is the same as for curves. It's hard to tell how you managed to make curve adapt to text radius however it does work how is described in the answer above.