# How to create 3D curved text the right way for boolean operations?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, text-object, 3d-printing

The duplicate question above is different from this question, is I need to boolean the text from a cilinder. And that requires converting it to a mesh, which messes up the text in similar matter shown below.

I want to do the following, but it doesn't yield nice results:

1. Create some text
2. Add Modifier "Curve"
3. <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> -> "Mesh from curve"
4. Give it some dimension: Add modifier "Solidify"

Then the result looks like this:
[image]

See especially the 'e'. I want to use this curved text to cut out the text from a cilinder. But that will never work propery as the letters are already messed up. Without curving they look fine, but I want it curved.

I must be possible to have nice curved 3D text in blender! How can I achieve this? I finally want to print

Thanks!

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6226/whats-the-simplest-way-to-wrap-extruded-text-around-a-cylinder , as I need text for boolean operations. And here there object is kept as text and not as a mesh..

Comment: You can easily convert it to a mesh after setting up the curve part.

Comment: But then it still looses smoothness and will look a but different because of the faces in the mesh.

Comment: You're right. Try adding a remesh modifier before the curve modifier: http://www.pasteall.org/pic/78835 Then Alt C works as expected for me.

Comment: Yes, the remesh did it, and also setting the resolution of the circle to curve to as explained here: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Curves