# How to slap a text object on to a sphere

Tags: text-object

Newbie here. I've looked through the answers to similar questions and am both in awe and perplexed by what I see. While I am sure that once I get the lingo down (solidify, mesh, remesh) it will all make sense, however I find that I have an urgent requirement and I'm only part way through the learning flow.

I need to create a few atoms. Quite simple really as far as I can tell, but I'm not there yet in the learning. I need a sphere with "H" on it (I guess the secret of which element it is is out).

There's a really good answer, apparently, on a question about creating balloons with text, but the language (peel off the pelt etc) used is well beyond me. Is there a location I should be looking to learn how to slap text onto a sphere?

Comment: Or [What's the simplest way to wrap extruded text around a cylinder?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6226/2217)