# Wrapping planes around a cylinder

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

so I want to wrap a few rectangles (like 2x4 pieces of lumber) partly around a cylinder (maybe 1/4-1/2) of the way and at an angle. I found a few ways to do this but all involve manually wrapping each section of the plane and feels like there should be an easier way to do this.

thanks

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78497/wrap-an-object-over-another-using-a-path and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6226/whats-the-simplest-way-to-wrap-extruded-text-around-a-cylinder

Comment: I was doing a search for a similar sort and was assisted by Rogue Lotus 4. Rogue assisted me by suggesting SHRINKWRAP Modifier and it worked for me. I hope it does for you too. Please click this link to take you to the page https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97651/how-to-wrap-multiple-3d-object-around-a-uv-sphere Cheers