# How to wrap multiple 3D objects around a UV sphere?

Tags: mesh, objects

I am a total NEWBIE in Blender.

I want to Wrap or Overlay (might be the wrong word to use) a 3D Mesh Object around on a UV Sphere (Mesh) and also want it to be laying on the surface of that Sphere. (Please see to the image I attached)

I have manually tried to lay the 3D Mesh Objects over the surface but it takes me ages to align the 3D Object on the surface of the Sphere.

Please help, thank you.[image]

Comment: Shrinkwrap modifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can understand you want your 3D mesh object to "wrap" around the sphere. I think the shrinkwrap modifier can help. [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Rogue Lotus 4, thank you heaps for your response. I will give it a try with your explanation.

Comment: Hi again Rogue Lotus 4, your tip has greatly helped me in my project. Thank you very much once again. Cheers

Comment: @PeterIbilo If this solved your issue, please consider accepting the answer, by clicking the checkmark to the left of it (just below the up and down arrows). This will signal to others with the same issue that this is a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

## Here is another way that works similarly.  The solution *is* more complex, but it still does what it seems you want.

I know I'm late, but I still want to answer this.

Select your UV sphere and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> -> Cursor to Selected.  Using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> add a Curve -> Circle.  Scale this up so it is slightly larger than the UV sphere, than rotate it on whatever axis: In my case, I used <kbd>R</kbd> > <kbd>Y</kbd> > <kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>. Now select your mesh, the person in this case. Under the *Properties* panel, *Modifiers* tab, add a *Curve* modifier.

[image: Adding the curve modifier to the mesh.]

Select the eyedropper in the *Object* data field, then click the new circle.

[image: Curve modifier in action.]

Make sure your cursor is still in the center of the UV sphere. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> -> Selection to Cursor.

[image: Oh no!] Now it seems the mesh is upside-down on the back. This can be fixed by mirroring the mesh with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd> on mac) + <kbd>M</kbd> -> then <kbd>Z</kbd> to mirror it across the Z axis. Now he is rightside up! You can now *Apply* the curve modifier (to the mesh being 'wrapped') and delete the circle.

#### Here is my final result:

[image: Image for the final result.]

You can now parent the 'wrapped' mesh to the UV sphere. Select the person, then  <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Right click the UV sphere. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> > (*Set parent to*) *Object*. Now whenever you move the sphere, the person will follow in the same place. This is especially good for rotating it.