# Making a embossing wheel using stl image around the wheel

Tags: modeling

I am brand new to Blender, I am trying to make a embossing wheel to imprint something like paper with a 3D design that wraps around the cylinder. The 3D design will be a animal in STL that is only 1-2mm thick but enough to show some detail just like say a Wedgwood cameo.

How can Blender do this?

Put it another way, how would you make a wheel or cylinder with a design embossed on the outside all the way around?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/emboss-text-onto-curved-surface https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195599/how-to-extrude-an-svg-on-surface-of-cylinder https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6226/whats-the-simplest-way-to-wrap-extruded-text-around-a-cylinder