# how to extrude an svg on surface of cylinder

Tags: extrude, 3d-printing

I want the fish that sits on the cylinder to extrude out off the smooth surface

Much like a fish stamp but on a curved surface.  I can get the fish curved on the surface but cannot get it to extrude

I have a cylinder and have imported an SVG and shrinkwrapped it top a cylinder.  How do I extrude the svg on surface of cylinder to it is raised/extruded (embossed)?

I tried to add midifier > solidify but the extrusion went crazy
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52904 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6226/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos that link does not seem to address my issue.  I need to extrude the image off the cylinder.  I already have it shrunkwrapped onto the surface

Comment: I can understand you need something different than the mentioned questions. But please clarify what you need: as I see it, do you want to extrude the outlines or obtain the whole shape embossed?

Comment: I want the fish that sits on the cylinder to extrude out off the smooth surface

Much like a fish stamp but on a curved surface. I can get the fish curved on the surface but cannot get it to extrude

Comment: Is the svg flat? Could you upload your blend file? (please use this link to do it: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: Again a question: if for 3d printing, do you really need it to be embeded in the same linked mesh?

Comment: maybe not.  I am new to blender/3dprinting.  open to suggestions.  You are correct the intention is to 3d print a roller stamp

Comment: If you don't need to have one connected mesh, so effectively this should answer the question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/44820/19156

Comment: A remark: the fish itself seems to have non manifold parts (check it using "select/all by trait" in edit mode)