# How do you extrude text in blender 2.8?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, text-object

Following:

[What's the simplest way to wrap extruded text around a cylinder?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6226/whats-the-simplest-way-to-wrap-extruded-text-around-a-cylinder)

I've managed to wrap and scale text around a (circle) Bezier curve. There seems to be, however, no extrude option in the tabs for blender 2.8. Where is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nvm. It's in the "Geometry" "text" tab.

[image]