# Shrinkwrap doesn't warp object around a target

Tags: shrinkwrap

I have problem with the `Shrinkwrap modifier` when I'm trying to warp an object around a target object. In most cases `Shrinkwrap` places an object to warp inside a target object instead of warping. Please see attached examples.

[image]

[image]

There I tried to warp the black pattern around the cylinder. You can see the result.

If I try to warp a Plane around a cylinder, it is just getting placed into the cylinder.

I am a really new in Blender. I spent a while trying to find solution but nothing.

Here is the source file:
[image]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: moonboots, just added, please check it now. Thank you for the reference btw!

Comment: For you information, shrinkwrap is not intended to wrap around.

Comment: as Lemon says you can't wrap a straight flat object on a cylinder, what you can do is using the curve modifier with a curve circle as Object, or use the Simple Deform/Bend modifier (don't forget to apply the rotation of your object).

Comment: Or: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6226/whats-the-simplest-way-to-wrap-extruded-text-around-a-cylinder

Comment: Thank you for the information and references. The references you sent me were partly helpful. I found out that my main problem was to make an object to bend a 'bendable'. I had to add some ribs and then it worked.