# Bending Mesh Around Another Mesh

Tags: objects

I am running Blender 2.93 on a Macbook Air. I am trying to bend one mesh around another mesh as shown in the photo (wrapping the text around the face of the cup). There is no manual for Mac that shows what keystrokes I need to use in order to do this.

Is there anyone that can point me in the right direction that shows how to do this ???

[image: 2 meshes]

Comment: hello, you can try the Bend mode of the Simple Deform modifier

Comment: I tried that, but the gizmo that i have seen in videos does NOT show up. I am running a Mac.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6226/whats-the-simplest-way-to-wrap-extruded-text-around-a-cylinder