# Shrink sleeve label on beer bottle

Tags: modeling, modifiers, uv

Can anyone tell me how to make, a shrink sleeve label in blender? Tried with shrink/wrap modifier but that's don't work. Tried several different methods but as far as I was able to wrap a label I still can't match it right. It's deformed and edges dont match.

Comment: you can do it in the material of the bottle itself

Comment: one way here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6226/whats-the-simplest-way-to-wrap-extruded-text-around-a-cylinder -> instead of text you could use any mesh object